# Did Tom Selleck threaten to quit Blue Bloods when executives pushed to remove the prayer from Sunday meals?

Tags: blue-bloods

I heard that executives were attempted to cut the saying of grace from *Blue Bloods*. Tom Selleck refused to accept this cut, and he even threatened his role as Frank Reagan over it.

I couldn't find anything in google, and was wondering if there was any veracity to this claim.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but Im sure that some gossip sites may have some useful information. whether they being truth or near truth is a fact that you should consider before trusting them completely anyway

Comment: From what I have read they did in fact come to diminish the prayer dinner scenes according to an article I found from October 2017, which included some outrage from many of the fans, but because I don't follow the show, I don't know what the results are and if those scenes are still watered down...https://popculture.com/tv-shows/2017/10/21/social-media-blue-bloods-dinner-scene-no-prayer/